# Mysql, join query , confused

Tags: mysql

the problem i face is , i would like to join these two queries.

```
   SELECT recipes.RecipeID ,recipes.Name,recipes.ImageThumb,recipes.RatingTotal,
   count(ratings.RecipeID) AS trates  
   FROM recipes 
        JOIN ratings 
            ON ratings.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
   WHERE recipes.Name LIKE '%ade%'  
   ORDER BY Name;
```

this query does not work as desired , it brings in 1 result when there are more then one , and the trates comes as the total of all the results , not just for that particular RecipeID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT recipes.RecipeID ,recipes.Name,recipes.ImageThumb,recipes.RatingTotal,
       COUNT(ratings.RecipeID) AS trates  
FROM recipes 
     LEFT JOIN ratings 
         ON ratings.RecipeID = recipes.RecipeID 
WHERE recipes.Name LIKE '%ade%'  
GROUP BY RecipeID 
ORDER BY Name;
```